# Reading a CSV file organized horizontally

Tags: r, csv, read.table

In R, is there a function like `read.csv` that reads in files where the headers are on the left (or right) as opposed to the top and the data is organized from left to right?

So the data would look like:

```
var1,1,2,3,4,5
```

Looking at the documentation for `read.table` and `read.csv`, nothing seems to pop out. The best option I see using those functions is to use `read.table` and then construct another table whose columns are the rows of the original data and so forth.

Comment: Can you give a minimal 2 or 3 line example of how your text data looks? Do you mean each line is just like: `var1,1,2,3,4,5`?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. So the header in this case is the left most column.

Comment: *if* all the variables are numeric then you can do as you suggested; `x <- read.csv(...); y <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(x[,-1])),as.character(x[,1]))`

Comment: That seems to work fairly well, with one exception. If the first row is supposed to be labels for the data, for example the year number, `read.csv` will append an `X` to each value. This is easily fixed manually though. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `read.table`, since `read.csv` is just a wrapper for that function with some of the arguments "hard coded". For example, `header = FALSE` might be helpful.

Comment: @BenBolker's comment is great. Would be convenient if `read.csv` or `readr::read_csv` had a logical `transpose=F` default that when true would become a wrapper for something like this!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's say your file is called 'data.csv' and it contains:

```
var1,1,2,3,4,5,6
var2,2.1,3.9,4.6,5.2,6.1
var3,M,F,M,F,M,M
```

Note `var1` and `var3` have 6 values but `var2` has only 5. 
So, the idea is to read the data, transpose it and then use `read.csv`.

```
read.tcsv = function(file, header=TRUE, sep=",", ...) {

  n = max(count.fields(file, sep=sep), na.rm=TRUE)
  x = readLines(file)

  .splitvar = function(x, sep, n) {
    var = unlist(strsplit(x, split=sep))
    length(var) = n
    return(var)
  }

  x = do.call(cbind, lapply(x, .splitvar, sep=sep, n=n))
  x = apply(x, 1, paste, collapse=sep) 
  out = read.csv(text=x, sep=sep, header=header, ...)
  return(out)

}
```

Then, you can do:

> read.tcsv("data.csv")

```
  var1 var2 var3
1    1  2.1    M
2    2  3.9    F
3    3  4.6    M
4    4  5.2    F
5    5  6.1    M
6    6   NA    M
```