# R data.frame : headers based on existing row containing text and numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

For some reason specific to my R program, I want to assign column names and row names based on existing column and row in a dataframe in R. 
That is to say, the first line has to become the column names, and the first column has to become the row names.

I first thought it was easy, using :

```
colnames(myDataFrame) <- myDataFrame[1,]
rownames(MyDataFrame) <- myDataFrame[,1]
```

As it is also written in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956119/assign-headers-based-on-existing-row-in-dataframe-in-r).

But I have a lot of cases to handle in the first row and first column of my data frame : only text, text with numbers, text or numbers...
That's why this sometimes does not work. See an example with only text in the first line :

I first load my data frame with no headers at all :

```
> tab <- read.table(file, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
> tab
         V1   V2  V3   V4   V5     V6  V7   V8   V9
1      TEST this  is only text hoping  it will work
2         I    4   0    0    0      0   0    0    1
3    really    7   6    6    3     10   6   10   10
4      hope  187 141  140  129    130 157  138  168
```

Here is my data frame without row and column names.
I want "TEST this  is only text hoping  it will work" to become my column name.
This doest not work :

```
> colnames(tab) <- tab[1,]
> tab
          2   10   9    9   10      8   9    8    9
1      TEST this  is only text hoping  it will work
2         I    4   0    0    0      0   0    0    1
3    really    7   6    6    3     10   6   10   10
4      hope  187 141  140  129    130 157  138  168
```

Whereas this works :

```
> colnames(tab) <- as.character(unlist(tab[1,]))
> tab
       TEST this  is only text hoping  it will work
1      TEST this  is only text hoping  it will work
2         I    4   0    0    0      0   0    0    1
3    really    7   6    6    3     10   6   10   10
4      hope  187 141  140  129    130 157  138  168
```

I thought the problem was because R sometimes considers the first column or row as factor.
But as you can see :

```
> is.factor(tab[1,])
FALSE
```

It can fail even if it is not converted as factor by R.

I tried to tip "as.character(unlist()))" in my program, but in some other cases that I might encounter, it no longer works !...
See an example with text and numbers in the first line :

```
> otherTab <- read.table(otherFile, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
> otherTab
               V1      V2     V3    V4  V5  V6    V7     V8    V9
1            TEST this45 is 486text 725 with ca257 some numbers
2        number45       4      0     0   0   0     0      0     1
3        254every       7      6     6   3  10     6     10    10
4           where     187    141   140 129 130   157    138   168

> colnames(otherTab) <- as.character(unlist(otherTab[1,]))
> otherTab
                6      10      9     7 725   8     9      8     9
1            TEST this45 is 486text 725 with ca257 some numbers
2        number45       4      0     0   0   0     0      0     1
3        254every       7      6     6   3  10     6     10    10
4           where     187    141   140 129 130   157    138   168
```

So how to handle these different cases in a easy way (because this seems to be a so simple problem) ?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because, in your initial data frame, `V5` is a column of type "int" , not a factor (so you have **two** different types in your first row)

```
#> str(df)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  9 variables:
# $ V1: Factor w/ 4 levels "254every","TEST",..: 2 3 1 4
# $ V2: Factor w/ 4 levels "187","4","7",..: 4 2 3 1
# $ V3: Factor w/ 4 levels "0","141","6",..: 4 1 3 2
# $ V4: Factor w/ 4 levels "0","140","486text",..: 3 1 4 2
# $ V5: int  725 0 3 129
# $ V6: Factor w/ 4 levels "0","10","130",..: 4 1 2 3
# $ V7: Factor w/ 4 levels "0","157","6",..: 4 1 3 2
# $ V8: Factor w/ 4 levels "0","10","138",..: 4 1 2 3
# $ V9: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","10","168",..: 4 1 2 3
```

All elements of a vector **must be of the same type**. When you try to `unlist()` and store the value in a vector to pass to `colnames()`, you actually pass a "int" vector (because R coerces the elements to a common type):

```
#> str(unlist(df[1,]))
# Named int [1:9] 2 4 4 3 725 4 4 4 4
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
```

If you modify the structure of your data frame to specify that column `V5` is a factor, your initial method would work:

```
df[,5] <- as.factor(df[,5])
colnames(df) <- unlist(df[1,])
```

You would get:

```
#> df
#      TEST this45  is 486text 725 with ca257 some numbers
#1     TEST this45  is 486text 725 with ca257 some numbers
#2 number45      4   0       0   0    0     0    0       1
#3 254every      7   6       6   3   10     6   10      10
#4    where    187 141     140 129  130   157  138     168
```

If you don't want to modify your column types, you could apply `as.character()` to each element of the first row before coercing to a vector and passing to `colnames()`:

```
colnames(df) <- lapply(df[1,], as.character)
```

Which results:

```
#> df
#      TEST this45  is 486text 725 with ca257 some numbers
#1     TEST this45  is 486text 725 with ca257 some numbers
#2 number45      4   0       0   0    0     0    0       1
#3 254every      7   6       6   3   10     6   10      10
#4    where    187 141     140 129  130   157  138     168
```

---

**Data**

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("254every", 
"TEST", "number45", "where"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("187", "4", "7", "this45"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "141", 
    "6", "is"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 
    2L), .Label = c("0", "140", "486text", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = c(725L, 0L, 3L, 129L), V6 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L), .Label = c("0", "10", "130", "with"), class = "factor"), 
    V7 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "157", 
    "6", "ca257"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "10", "138", "some"), class = "factor"), 
    V9 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "10", "168", 
    "numbers"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Steven. This made my day :
colnames(df) <- lapply(df[1,], as.character).
Thank you for all your explainations !