# Combining multifiles and add unique ID for each of them

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I am newbie in R. I got a problem when combining data, hope that someone help to resolve it.
Suppose that I have two CSV files such as A.csv and B.csv are located at the path "C:\Users\Public\A".
They look like that:

A.csv

`T,2015,2016,2017,2018
X1,1,2,3,2
X2,1,2,2,3
X3,1,3,4,2`

B.csv

`T,2015,2016,2017
X1,2,4,3
X2,2,2,3
X3,3,3,4`

And then I try to combine them as well as transpose them with following functions. They are created by Ricardo Oliveros-Ramos at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288197/reading-a-csv-file-organized-horizontally) and by Tony Cookson at [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-multiple-data-files-into-one-data-frame/).
1. Firstly, I create function `read.tcsv` to read and transpose data in CSV file

```
  read.tcsv = function(file, header=TRUE, sep=",", ...) {
  n = max(count.fields(file, sep=sep), na.rm=TRUE)
  x = readLines(file)

  .splitvar = function(x, sep, n) {
    var = unlist(strsplit(x, split=sep))
    length(var) = n
    return(var)
  }

  x = do.call(cbind, lapply(x, .splitvar, sep=sep, n=n))
  x = apply(x, 1, paste, collapse=sep) 
  out = read.csv(text=x, sep=sep, header=header, ...)
  return(out)

}
```

2. Then I use `multrbind.fill` to combine and fill missing value

```
multrbind.fill = function(mypath){
  filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
  datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){
    read.tcsv(file=x,header=T)
  }
)
    Reduce(function(x,y) {plyr::rbind.fill(x,y)}, datalist)
}
```

3. The result looks good:

`ï..T   X1  X2  X3
2015    1   1   1
2016    2   2   3
2017    3   2   4
2018    2   3   2
2015    2   2   3
2016    4   2   3
2017    3   3   4`

4. However, I want to add a column as an identifier for each file with their file name (or unique IDs) like that:

`ï..T   ID    X1    X2  X3
2015    A      1    1   1
2016    A      2    2   3
2017    A      3    2   4
2018    A      2    3   2
2015    B      2    2   3
2016    B      4    2   3
2017    B      3    3   4`

Someone help me!? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks ***TJ83*** for helping me to correct the function. Base on ***TJ83***'s comments, I add an identifier column named ID. And here is my complete function `read.tcsv`

```
read.tcsv = function(file, header=TRUE, sep=",", ...) {
  n = max(count.fields(file, sep=sep), na.rm=TRUE)
  x = readLines(file)

  .splitvar = function(x, sep, n) {
    var = unlist(strsplit(x, split=sep))
    length(var) = n
    return(var)
  }

  x = do.call(cbind, lapply(x, .splitvar, sep=sep, n=n))
  x = apply(x, 1, paste, collapse=sep)

out = read.csv(text=x, sep=sep, header=header, ...)
out$ID<-tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file))
return(out)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you only have 2 datasets, then the fastest way would be to add an ID-column on A and B datasets after transformation but before binding the rows.

```
Dataset_A$ID<-"A"
Dataset_B$ID<-"B"
# Where Dataset_X is the name of your imported transformed datasets.
```

2) Could you show your exact code used? If you only have 2 datasets I think the code you have created could be simplified substantially. If you are interested in a simplification then please supply us with output from the 2 dput-statements below:

```
A<-read.csv("A-dataset")
B<-read.csv("B-dataset")
dput(A)
dput(B)
```

Comment: In fact, I have more than 350 CSV files in folder A, so I have to use function `multrbind.fill` to combine all of them at once.

Comment: I call name of these files by `tools` with `file_path_sans_ext(list.files(file.path(mypath)))`. But, I do not know how to add it into the data frame properly.

Comment: Here is the output of my result: 


    `dput(multirbind("C:/Users/Vu Quang Vinh/Desktop/A"))
    structure(list(ï..T = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2015L, 2016L, 
2017L), X1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L), X2 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), X3 = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))`

Comment: When you do it all in one step and I don't have access to the csv-files, it is very difficult to reproduce.

`read.tcsv(file=x,header=T)
}`

Between the 2 lines you should add something like `x$ID<-paste(x)`

Comment: You can create 2 CSV files like A.csv and B.csv that I mentioned above. And then using `read.tcsv` as well as `mulrbind.fill` to reproduce the result. I also tried your suggestion but it doesn't work :(.

Comment: Last try... Between the two lines:
'out = read.csv(text=x, sep=sep, header=header, ...)' 'return(out)'. Add 'out$ID<-paste(x)'

Comment: The error due to difference rows. 
`Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "ID", value = c("ï»¿T,X1,X2,X3", "2015,1,1,1", : replacement has 5 rows, data has 4`
Btw, thank you very much!